# Is there a program that allows me to design a Regex using a Finite State Machine Graph?

Tags: regex, state-machine

I'm sick of Regex notation.  It's ugly, unreadable, and impossible to debug.  However, mathemeticians have been using Finite State Machines to design regular expressions for decades.

[image: Finite State Machines]

If I'm getting annoyed by regexes, I'll go and draw it out as a finite state machine by hand, and then have to translate the finite state machine into whatever hideous regex syntax I'm using today.

Is there a program that lets me design finite state machines and spit out a regex?

Comment: There are somethings which are supported by regular expressions which aren't in finite state machines.

Comment: I've not heard of such a programme; you might have to create it yourself. Maybe a script for inkscape?

Comment: In the days when Sussman was a novice Minsky once came to him as he
sat hacking at the PDP-6. "What are you doing?" asked Minsky. "I am training a randomly wired neural net to play Tic-Tac-Toe." "Why is the net wired randomly?" asked Minsky. "I do not want it to have any preconceptions of how to play." Minsky shut his eyes. "Why do you close your eyes?" Sussman asked his teacher. "So that the room will be empty."

Answer (score 3):

If you know Python, you can try [greenery](https://github.com/ferno/greenery). The package `fsm` is for finite state machines, and `lego` is for regular expression objects. The two can be freely interconverted.

```
>>> from greenery import fsm
>>> x = fsm.fsm(
...     alphabet={"1", "2"},
...     states={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"},
...     initial="A",
...     finals={"E"},
...     map={
...         "A": {"1": "C", "2": "A"},
...         "B": {"1": "B", "2": "D"},
...         "C": {"1": "E", "2": "C"},
...         "D": {"1": "A", "2": "B"},
...         "E": {"1": "C", "2": "D"}
...     }
... )
>>> print(x.lego())
(1(11|2)*12(21*2)*1|2)*1(11|2)*1
```

I feel I should point out that your example finite state machine lacks both an initial state and any final states, so I guessed them. Also, an arbitrary FSM usually converts into a pretty horrible regular expression, and simplifying a regular expression is computationally difficult...

Answer (score 1):

> JFLAP is software for experimenting with formal languages topics including nondeterministic finite automata, nondeterministic pushdown automata, multi-tape Turing machines, several types of grammars, parsing, and L-systems. In addition to constructing and testing examples for these, JFLAP allows one to experiment with construction proofs from one form to another, such as converting an NFA to a DFA to a minimal state DFA to a regular expression or regular grammar.

[**JFLAP**](http://www.jflap.org/)

Comment: ah, registerware. Sweet :-)